# Is this "Wandering Dwarf" subrace balanced?

Tags: dnd-5e, balance, homebrew-review, dwarf

In a campaign setting I designed, the Dwarves are wandering nomads who rarely stay in one place. I created the following subrace for these nomads, and I was wondering if it was balanced.

Wandering Dwarf:

> Ability Score Increase: Your Dexterity Score increases by 1.

Idea: To make them more agile, a thematic increase and similar to other subraces.

> Fleet of Foot: Your walking speed increases to 30 feet.

Idea: Similar to the Wood Elf, increasing their speed to the average for a PC.

> Perseverance: You are immune to the effects of a forced march if your march for 12 hours or less in a day.

Idea: Mostly thematic (most campaigns don't deal with the mechanics of travel, and unless there is a party of all Wandering Dwarves, this won't come into effect).

> Life of a Nomad: You are proficient in the Nature, Perception, and Survival skills.

Idea: This trait is supposed to make them better at travel, allowing them to identify plants, more easily spot things, and track creatures-all useful nomad skills.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Everything here is in line with the other races other than Life of a Nomad. 3 Proficiencies is a lot. Perception is also arguably the most rolled skill in the game and in my opinion has the least relevancy to the theme. I would probably remove the perception and say that it is a perfectly fine subrace.

Comment: Okay. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: Your answer hits the exact points I'd make. +1, and welcome to RPGSE! 